# Implementing profile and extention data using Selenium with Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Implements Profile and Option (extention in this case) into Firefox using Selenium

```py
# Profile Path is ff_p
# Extention Path is ff_e

from selenium import webdriver

ff_p = r"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\8ijzs0hk.default-release"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(ff_p)

ff_e = r"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\8ijzs0hk.default-release\extensions\{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}.xpi"
driver.install_addon(ff_e, temporary=True)

driver.get("https://example.com")
```